# Why does <span> exceed <div> width?

Tags: css

how do i get the `<span>` to be within the `<div>` that contains the image? the right side is too long.

```
  .image-container {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .image-container img {display: block;}

        .image-container .after {
            display: block;

        }
        .image-container .after .content {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #C0D8D8;
            bottom: 0;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0px;
        }


<div class="after">
                <div class="content"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">this is some content. It can be long and span several lines.</a></div>
            </div>
```

[image: the width of the text box is larger than the div that contains the image]

Comment: where is `span`?

Comment: add a <span> :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.after {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 200px;
}

.after img {
    width: 100%;
}

.after .content {
    background-color: #C0D8D8;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="after">
    <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg">
    <span class="content"><a href="#">this is some content. It can be long and span several lines.this is some content. It can be long and span several lines.this is some content. It can be long and span several lines.this is some content. It can be long and span several lines.</a>
    </span>
</div>
```